# Бесконечный вывод при вводе * в bash

Tags: linux, bash, wildcards, glob

Почему при вводе в bash:

```
user@user:~/Desktop/Library$ *
```

Возникает бесконечный вывод непонятных символов?
Cодержимое каталога:

```
user@user:~/Desktop/Library$ ls
cat  D.pdf  Linux.pdf  VBash.pdf
```

После того как заменил .pdf файлы на пустые текстовые файлы с такими же названиями это прошло:

```
user@user:~/Desktop/Library$ *
user@user:~/Desktop/Library$ ls
cat  D.pdf  Linux.pdf  VBash.pdf
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас в текущей директории находятся 4 файла: `cat`, `D.pdf`, `Linux.pdf` и `VBash.pdf`.

Символ `*` в языке bash это так называемый wildcard ([шаблон поиска](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0)), который соответствует всем файлам в текущем каталоге.

Если же ввести в командную строку просто `*`, то такой wildcard развернется в список всех файлов в вашей директории, но в то же время это будет валидной командой для bash:

```
cat D.pdf Linux.pdf VBash.pdf
```

Поэтому на экране вы увидите содержимое трех `pdf` файлов. Если [`pdf`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF)-файл содержит в себе бинарные данные, то скорей всего на экране вы увидите большое количество "непонятных" символов.

Comment: Думаю стоит отметить что в терминале возможен вывод только текстовых файлов, бинарные файлы как раз будут выводить "иероглифы"